# NodeRed Server: Install custom nodes while running

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-cloud, node-red

I run an NodeJS server with an website on Bluemix. In addition I use the embedded Node-Red module (http://nodered.org/docs/embedding.html) to run a Node-Red server in the background to use it on my website.

Now I want to add/update my custom nodes while the server runs.

Working Environment: Bluemix, Node.JS Express 4, Node-Red module

I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

The Node-RED runtime includes an admin api that allows you to install nodes whilst the system is running.

See: http://nodered.org/docs/api/admin/methods/post/nodes/